# SQL for amount of days since specified date each year (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I'm trying to get the amount of days it has been since April 15th from the current date, excluding the year so that no matter what its never greater than 365

When this is performed:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, '04/15/2015', GETDATE())
```

it will only work for this year and need to get it to work for each year.

Comment: your taxes are past due, but don't forget the days when because of weekends it's not 4/15...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need conditional logic to handle dates before April 15th in the current year:

```
SELECT (case when month(getdate()) > 4 or
                  month(getdate()) = 4 and day(getdate()) > 15
             then DATEDIFF(day, cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(255)) + '-04-15', GETDATE())
             else DATEDIFF(day, cast(year(getdate()) - 1 as varchar(255)) + '-04-15', GETDATE())

        end)
```

Comment: Thanks and works perfect on boundary dates of April 14, 15, 16

Answer (score 1):

Just pop the current year into your query

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, '04/15/'+ CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS CHAR(4)), GETDATE())
```

Comment: this will return negative values if the date is before the 15th -- see Gordan's answer if you want to check the prior year.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(diff)
FROM ( VALUES
  ( DATEDIFF(day,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())  ,4,15),GETDATE()) )
 ,( DATEDIFF(day,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1,4,15),GETDATE()) )
) t(diff)
WHERE diff >= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "dy" interval to get the number of days that have passed so far in the year for "today".  Getting the number of days for April 15th is a little trickier because of the potential for a leap year.  Best to construct a date object and ask SQL Server to resolve it to a number of days for you.

I would avoid using date strings in your query if you can.  The string to date conversion costs you some processing time which, if there are a lot of rows involved, can really add-up.  Also, using a string tightly couples you to that date format.

If you're using SQL Server 2012 or higher:

```
SELECT DATEPART(dy, GETDATE()) - DATEPART(dy, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 4, 15));
```

For < SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT DATEPART(dy, GETDATE()) 
    - DATEPART(dy, DATEADD(dd, 14, DATEADD(mm, 3, DATEADD(yy, YEAR(GETDATE())-1900, 0))));
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you give me an example case where this fails?  2017 is a year that follows a leap year and it seems OK.  Thanks.

Comment: Wrong problem.  Your queries will return negative numbers for dates between Jan 1 and Apr 14.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I see.  The OP asked for "amount of days it has been since April 15th from the current date".  I assumed that meant within the current calendar year.  I didn't realize that April 15th was to be day "1" of the year; more like a fiscal year.